# Debugging WordPress with PhpStorm and a local deploy setup

Tags: wordpress, intellij-idea, phpstorm

I like to keep my project files clean.

E.g. I keep all the files I manipulate in my project folder, and deploy them on to my local developer server on save.

e.g. if I write a theme for WordPress I create:

```
wp-content
wp-content/themes/
wp-content/themes/mytheme
```

I certainly don't keep all the files of the whole WordPress installation in my project.

I include those over the include path, then it shows as external libraries
those include all files of WordPress including mine.

[image]

Now here comes trouble

When I now press F3 on one of my functions I get "Choose declaration"

[image]

well I don't want code on my local deployment never! I always want to code in my project source files, that is, not in "external libraries"

so basically

when I add the include path, I want to have the ability to say

"excluded sub-directory of that include path"

so I can exclude my deployed files from the library. Do you understand what I mean?

is that possible?

"well just remove the include path"

no! without include path I cannot debug. Without include path I don't get auto-complete

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out

the trick was in the end to not use "include path" but the project structure editor and add a different content root folder.

FIle - project structure

or

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SHIT</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>

looks like this:

[image]

click on your module, click on add content root folder, click on the target deploy folder of your deployment scripts, and then exclude the stuff you don't like

it will create a new folder in the project explorer but i don't care about that really.

Remove it from the include that i mentioned in my post earlier, i mean from settings - php - external libraries. YOu don't need that any longer

hope it helps